# Rails route only if resource is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to have a rails route that triggers if the given id is present, but falls back to further route matching if not.

Specifically, I want to have promo codes at the root level of my site.  So, you can go to `foo.com/save87` or `foo.com/xmasspecial`, and it'll treat it as a promo code, but if you go to a promo code that's not there (`foo.com/badcode`), that route will not match and rails will continue down the route list.

In an ideal world, I'd do something like this in my `routes.rb` file:

```
get '/:promo_id' => 'promos#show, constraints => lambda { Promo.exists?(promo_id) }
```

I know that the above code, without the constraints, would work as a catch-all for `foo.com/*`, and would sorta work if I put it as the last line in the routes file.  Unfortunately, that would result in `foo.com/badcode` a 'promocode not found' error, rather than a normal 'route not found' error.

So, is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?  This is in Rails 3, for reference.

---

Edit: To clarify a bit-

- I want a wildcard url as described above so that our promocode urls are short and memorable (`foo.com/save87` instead of `foo.com/promo_codes/save87`)
- I'd prefer to have the option of having other routes after this one.  I may, at some point, need another wildcard url at the root level- for example, if I want vanity urls for another resource in my system.  For example, if I sell a dozen varieties of widgets, I might want `foo.com/widget_deluxe`, `foo.com/widget_extreme`, etc in addition to my promo code urls.  I'd have to make sure that there's no collision between promo codes and widget varieties, but that's easily handled elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to couple this in the route and not handle the logic in the controller?

Comment: Well, is there any way to get back out of a controller if the controller determines that the given promo code doesn't exist?  That is, if the promo code doesn't exist, I want the router to continue trying to match routes.  I'd be glad to do this in the controller if that option exists.

Comment: Do you expect other routes to pass if the one with the `promo_id` fails? Do you have an example for such a route?

Comment: Yes, that's the hope.  Ideally, I'd like to have *any* route the follows the promo_id one have a chance to pass, whether it's one of my static routes like `/faq` or another wildcard one (although, of course, I'd have to make sure there's no collision between promocodes and any other wildcards I put at the root level).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In an ideal world, I'd do something like this in my routes.rb file:

No way. In `Rails` World, this functionality should go inside controller.

In controller you can do something like

```
def show
  if Promo.exists?(promo_id)
    #do something
  else
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```

**Update**

With routes, you can do something like this

```
constraints(lambda { |req| Promo.exists?(req.params["promo_id"]) }) do
    get '/:promo_id' => 'promos#show
end
```

Please keep in mind that this constraints will query the database for every request with a url matching the pattern `/:promo_id` (e.q. `/users`, `/faq`). To avoid unnecessary database queries that decrease your website performance, you should add this rule as far as possible to the end of your `routes.rb`.

Comment: I agree that the controller is where this logic *should* reside, but that doesn't accomplish what I'm going for.  Raising a routing error in the controller just kills the request.  What I want is for route matching to continue if the promo code doesn't exist.

Comment: @Fishtoaster Perhaps it is a good idea not only to explain what you want to accomplish, but why you want to do so...

Comment: I've tried to clarify a bit in an edit to the question above.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Fishtoaster, updated the answer. Never used any such type code, wish it will work.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar: Your answer with the `constraints` is correct, but perhaps you want to add a warning that this pattern will query the database for every request coming in and therefore slow down the whole webpage?

Comment: @spickermann No, that wouldn't be the case. The database query is only loaded when `routes` matches  the format.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar: Sure, not *every* request. But @Fishtoaster said he wants to add the route not at the end of the `routes.rb`, but before routes like `/faq` or other static pages. Therefore it would query the database unnecessarily for that kind of routes.

Comment: @spickermann yes, please you update the answer as per your opinion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using this routing logic, every request to your application would do an extra search for a promo code before it moved on to the rest of the routes.  I recommend looking at your business case and consider doing a Promo controller.  If you must do routes, something like this would work but I would put it at the end so that it goes to your regular routes first.

```
get '*', to: 'promos#show'
```

Comment: Of course, my current fallback plan is to talk my client into doing a controller: `foo.com/p/save87` or something.  I can understand their desire for shorter, more memorable urls like `foo.com/save87`, though and I'd like to accomplish it if possible.